# How do I validate a date in YYYY-MM-DD format in Perl?

Tags: perl, date, validation

> Related/Possible duplicate: [How can I validate dates in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297398/how-can-i-validate-dates-in-perl)

I have created a script where start and end date needs to be given by user while executing the script. The date format entered by user should be in `YYYY-MM-DD` format only.

```
start_date = $ARGV[0];
end_date = $ARGV[1];
```

please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you mean is

```
$start_date = $ARGV[0];
$end_date = $ARGV[1];
```

i.e. syntactically valid Perl code, then you might do something like

```
die "Please enter dates in YYYY-MM-DD format\n"
    unless $start_date =~ /^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d$/;
die "Please enter dates in YYYY-MM-DD format\n"
    unless $end_date =~ /^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d$/;
```

Answer (score 5):

As noted by others, this could be done with [regular expressions](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=614932).  However, if you want to quickly implement a complete and robust solution, then CPAN is your friend.

[This TechRepublic article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manipulate-dates-and-time-with-these-10-perl-cpan-modules/) contains a good comparison of Date & Time modules on CPAN.

For your particular use, you should consider [`Time::Normalize`](http://search.cpan.org/~roode/Time-Normalize-0.03/Normalize.pm).  See the [`Diagnostics`](http://search.cpan.org/~roode/Time-Normalize-0.03/Normalize.pm#DIAGNOSTICS) section of its documentation.

See also [How can I validate dates in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297398/how-can-i-validate-dates-in-perl) on SO.

Answer (score 3):

First,

```
my ($start_date, $end_date) = @ARGV;
```

works too.

```
if ( $var =~ /^(?<year>[0-9]{4})-(?<month>[0-9]{2})-(?<day>[0-9]{2})$/ ) {
    # see %+ in perldoc perlvar
```

Now, you need to make sure the values are valid years, months and days.

Comment: You should note that named captures require Perl 5.10 and (probably) provide a fallback for older versions.