# How can I validate a "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" date/timestamp in UTC with Perl?

Tags: perl, validation, datetime

Code would be nice but a point in the right direction is good as well.

CPAN? RegEx?

I've seen both ways

"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";

"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ";

Comment: You might also want to see "How can I validate dates in Perl?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297398/how-can-i-validate-dates-in-perl

Comment: Is "yyyy" Y10K-compliant? :D Seriously though, I would just used `\d{4,}-` for the first section.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ether is definitely on the right track with DateTime.  Using DateTime, you can be sure that you have a time that actually exists, where something on Feb 29, 2000 might get by if you wrote the checks yourself.

Your format looks like an ISO8601 string.  So, use [DateTime::Format::ISO8601](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-Format-ISO8601/lib/DateTime/Format/ISO8601.pod) to do your parsing.

```
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::ISO8601;

my $string = '2010-02-28T15:21:33Z';

my $dt = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->parse_datetime( $string );
die "Impossible time" unless $dt;
```

You could use other format modules, such as [D::F::Strptime](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-Format-Strptime/lib/DateTime/Format/Strptime.pm), but you will wind up recreating what ISO8601 formatter already does.

Comment: DateTime must be one of the most useful and well designed modules ever written in any language, IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you're doing, you might want to coerce your string into a [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DateTime) object, e.g.:

```
use DateTime::Format::MySQL;
my $dt = DateTime::Format::MySQL->parse_datetime( '2003-01-16 23:12:01' );
```

Then you can easily output your time string in a different format, perform calculations with it, etc.

You didn't specify what is generating the string in that particular format, but there are DateTime::Format:: modules for a large number of input sources.

Comment: if I supply the datetime can I use this to convert it to UTC?

Comment: @Phil: you mean once you have the DateTime object constructed, can you convert between timezones? Absolutely: see the DateTime docs: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DateTime; the strftime() method will return a string in whatever format you specify.