# Perl - How to convert a date?

Tags: perl, date, format

How to convert date format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM + 8 hours?

For example:

```
Input: 2011-07-07T18:05:45Z

Output: 2011-07-08 02:05
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's start with Rahul's snippet, and add in the date math and output formatting...

```
use DateTime; 
use DateTime::Format::ISO8601;

use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $string = '2011-07-07T18:05:45Z';
my $dt = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->parse_datetime( $string ); 
die "Impossible time" unless $dt;

my $formatter = new DateTime::Format::Strptime(pattern => '%Y-%m-%d %T');
$dt->add( hours => 8 )->set_formatter($formatter);
print "$dt\n";
```

I've added the use of DateTime::Format::Strptime, in order to specify the desired output format.

Then I've added three more lines:

1. First I create a formatter, and feed it the output pattern I desire.
2. Next    I add eight hours to the original date, and I assign the output
   formatter by chaining the set_formatter() call to the add() call.
3. Then I print it.

Comment: If there are DST transitions, then all answers can be equally wrong depending on what you want and what you're doing with the result. I don't have a system handy to test with, but I'd like to see the results of such transitions.

Comment: In combination wih Time::Seconds, Time::Piece actually does offer calculations (on hours, seconds, minutes and days), and without Time::Seconds exports add_months and add_years.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-0.70/lib/DateTime.pm) modules?

Specifically, here's a link to [DateTime::Format::ISO8601](http://search.cpan.org/~jhoblitt/DateTime-Format-ISO8601-0.07/lib/DateTime/Format/ISO8601.pod#5.4_Combinations_of_date_and_time_of_day) that reads/writes ISO 8601 format you mentioned as your input.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have DateTime, you surely have Time::Piece:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds qw(ONE_HOUR);

my $str = '2011-07-07T18:05:45Z';
my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($str, "%Y-%m-%dT%TZ");
$t += 8 * ONE_HOUR;
print $t->strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),"\n";
```

Comment: Time::Seconds provides constants to make this more clear: something like use Time::Seconds; $t += (8 * ONE_HOUR)

Answer (score 0):

Taken From

[How can I validate a "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" date/timestamp in UTC with Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088651/how-can-i-validate-a-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmssz-date-timestamp-in-utc-with-perl)

```
use DateTime; 
use DateTime::Format::ISO8601;
my $string = '2010-02-28T15:21:33Z';
my $dt = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->parse_datetime( $string ); die "Impossible time" unless $dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

> It doesn't work, result is 2010-02-28T15:21:33

Then, do it the hard way...

```
use Time::Local
use warnings;
use strict;

$time = '2010-02-28T15:21:33Z';

my ($year, month, day) = split (/-/, $time)
$year -= 1900;   #Year is an offset of 1900
$month -= 1;     #Months are 0 - 11

#Now split the time off of the day (DDTHH:MM:SS)

$day = substr($day, 0, 2);
time = substr($day, 3)

#Now split the time

(my $hour, $minute, $second) = split(/:/, $time);

$second =~ s/Z$//;  #Remove Z

my $time_converted = timelocal($second, $minute, $hour, $day, $month, $year);

#Now you have the time, Add eight hours

my $hours_in_seconds = 8 * 60 * 60;
$time_converted += $hours_in_seconds;

# Almost done: Convert time back into the correct array:

($second, $minute, $hour, $day, $month, $year) = localtime($time_converted);

$year += 1900;
$month += 1;

# Now, reformat:

my $formatted_time = sprint (%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d), 
    $year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute;
```