# How can I convert yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss into UTC in Perl?

Tags: perl, datetime, format, utc

convert datetime format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss (Might be a string) into UTC,
Looking into DateTime but I don't see how to parse the string?

UPDATE:

Is this working correctly?

```
require 5.002;

use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime::Format::DateManip;

my $string = '2010-02-28 00:00:00';

my @dates = (
    $string
);

for my $date ( @dates ) {
    my $dt = DateTime::Format::DateManip->parse_datetime( $date );
    die "Cannot parse date $date, Please use a valid date in this format 'yyyy-mm-dd mm:hh:ss'"  unless defined $dt;
    print $dt."\n";
    $dt->set_time_zone( 'UTC' );
    print $dt."Z\n"; # Is this correct???
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this SO question, [How can I validate dates in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297398/how-can-i-validate-dates-in-perl) for one answer.

There are also some nice [`DateTime`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime/) helper modules on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org). For eg. [`DateTimeX::Easy`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTimeX-Easy/) which allows you to create [DateTime](http://datetime.perl.org) objects like so:

```
use DateTimeX::Easy;

my $a_date    = DateTimeX::Easy->new( '11/17/2008 12:01am' );

my $tomorrow  = DateTimeX::Easy->new( 'tomorrow' );

my $last_week = DateTimeX::Easy->new( 'last week' );
```

/I3az/

Comment: this led me to my solution, see UPDATE. Thanks again

Comment: No probs.  However I'm not sure what your "Is this correct?" edit is referring to?   If no time zone is provided in the date/time string being parsed then your local TZ is assumed for it.  The $dt->set_time_zone() then allows you to see the DateTime object you have but from a different timezone perspective.  Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 3):

```
use DateTime::Format::ISO8601;
my $dt = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->parse_datetime('yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss');
```

Use the [DateTime::Format::ISO8601](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DateTime::Format::ISO8601) module to parse that format and give you back a [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DateTime) object.

Answer (score 2):

You need one of the parse methods in a DateTime::Format::* module.

Your string doesn't quite look like ISO8601 format (which is 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss'), but it matches [MySQL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DateTime::Format::MySQL)'s formatting style:

```
use DateTime::Format::MySQL;
my $dt = DateTime::Format::MySQL->parse_datetime('2010-02-28 00:00:00');

print $dt->strftime("%Y %M %d %T");
```

produces:

> 2010 00 28 00:00:00

Comment: @daxim: the question that I answered was very vague (if you look in the edit history, it was only one line).

Comment: @daxim: please check again, working code and reference added. Today has been a bad day for me for downvotes and I'd like to fix that! :)